# HTTP requests to a server hang up in node, but still work in-browser

Tags: http, networking

I'm making hundreds of requests from Node to a wikia website (namely, `https://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/`).

After a variable amount of requests, the requests just hang indefinitely, and I need to wait a while before I continue.

I'd take it for a DDOS protection, however requests from within the browser do not hang up (they only occasionally slow down a little bit for a few seconds). Even if I copy some headers (cookies/user-agent) over to Node, it still does hang up, while the browser does not.

What could be the perpetrator here? How do I go about it? What tools do I need?

Comment: The code could be sending out requests much faster than a person is capable of in a browser, did you try measuring the average time needed to send out a request in node? Are you using any libraries for sending out the requests? (if yes, perhaps something in the library can be rate-limiting, you should check out the documentation for your specific library if you think that could be the case)

Comment: @Expolarity It occurs with all HTTP libraries I've tried, and there were more than 4. The in-browser fetches were done by a script as well, it was just a while-true-await-fetch loop.